# What happens to the other NSManagedObjects on a context when context.reset() is called?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a scenario where an Entity has many relationships with other entities. I did some changes in the NSManagedObject of the entity and discarded those changes.

Right now I'm calling `managedObjectContext.refresh(entity, mergeChanges: false)` and then `managedObjectContext.refresh(relatedEntity, mergeChanges: false)` on every related entity to ensure having no dangling objects in the context.

What would be the difference if I directly call `managedObjectContext.reset()`? Should I still need to refresh or mark nil the related entities?

Is there any way to make this code more optimized?

Answer (score 0):

If you call `reset`, you need to also immediately stop using every managed object you have fetched from that context. All fetches need to be redone after the `reset`, because it makes the context forget about everything it has already fetched.

There are various patterns for more efficiently creating discardable changes like you describe. One popular choice is:

1. Create a new managed object context and make it a child context of the current context.
2. Make your changes in that context.
3. If you want to save changes, save them. If not, just don't bother. The child context will be deallocated and its changes will be lost.

Comment: Hi, I have used the same approach as a parent-child context. It's just that after discarding the changes in my child context I might again do some changes in the same child context. So I'm not very sure how to manage such a scenario.

Comment: I mean to create a new child context for the discardable changes. Don't make new changes in the same child context, create a new child context for the new changes.